# Javascript loaded in random order fails to initialize

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I get my javascript loaded in an undetermined order. I have a namespace function to register namespaces. For example it's possible to write something like this:

```
"com.stackoverflow.question".namespace(new function() {
    this.sayHelloTo = function(text) { alert("Hello" + text); }
});
```

Unfortunately the `namespace.js` isn't always loaded first, as the loading order is random but the other scripts make use of the namespace function. Is there a way to achieve this without getting the error "`.namespace`" ist not a function?

So there must be a way to initialize the `sayHelloTo` definition later, I have an everything is loaded event. So the upcoming statement works but it's very ugly I think.

```
var postInit = postInit || [];
postInit.push(function() {
  "com.foo.bar".namespace(new function() {
      this.sayHelloTo = function(text) { alert(text); }
  });
});
```

And when the event occurs:

```
list.foreach(function(k, v) { v.call();  });
```

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AMD: take a look at http://requirejs.org/.  Alternately common.js may work depending on the use.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I can't include the javascripts on my own. I'm not in a browser envrionment, I'm in a framework where the js files are compiled in a random order. So I have simply NO access or possibility to load/require scripts.

Comment: What kind of framework includes js files in random order? What are you using?

Comment: It's slightly more complicated then but the same principles apply. You could also just copy and paste a library into the code you're stuck with (there's nothing browser specific about require).

Wrap every function that has a dependency in an outer function and then attach that outer function to a queue that is processed when the dependency is loaded (use events if you're comfortable with them).  If for some reason you can't even do that, then polling for namespace definition may be the only option and process the queue at that time.

Comment: We're inside a closed source framework where your js files just get executed in a random order, the only event I get is the `postLoad()` event. So I have to come up with something else :-/

Comment: @MattWhipple: Ok, but even the require JS framework may be executed as the last javascript. So how does this queue work when it may be unintialized? Is it simliar to my approach? Maybe you can explain how it works?

Comment: Your approach is good so long as it works, most libraries will be doing something similar internally.  An alternative that may be simpler is to just move each dependent declaration into a handler for the "everything is loaded" event, rather than even bothering with a queue.  The queue concept would be more useful if you were dealing with a higher level of granularity.  If you're just throwing everything into the same queue, it's just a needless layer on top of event handling.

Comment: That still doesn't manage dependencies between scripts, however. E.g., if a plugin-defining script requires the core library that it's plugging into to have been loaded first. There's a good reason that browsers load script tags synchronously (blocking, in order of declaration). This "closed source framework where your js files just get executed in a random order" seems pretty fishy to me. Like, fundamentally broken, if that's indeed how it works. This namespacing exercise aside, how is that even supposed to work in general.

Comment: The plugin registration could also be deferred so long as they're loaded by the js.  All of this could be worked through with the right events and callbacks, but without some support for deterministic loading it is just inviting bugs and enough workarounds that any conceptual benefit is more than outweighed by complexity and barrier of entry.  I was going to say that _fundamentally broken_ may be a bit harsh, but frameworks are supposed to help developers...if it's making things more difficult without providing paths through then it would be some form of anti-framework.

Comment: The framework is indeed fishy, but I can't do anything against it except making the best out of it. If you want to know the name of the framework I'll send you a PM. @MattWhipple: Can you give me an example, what you mean with "[..] just move each dependent declaration into a handler [...]"?

Comment: @codevour - what is the syntax for binding events using this framework?